# Bundling Kotlin runtime with my jar in grade

Tags: kotlin, minecraft-forge

I'm making a minecraft mod with kotlin, gradle and the forge modding api. Whenever I place the the mod in the mods folder used by forge, I get an error which I will put below. The error suggests the kotlin runtime is not in my .jar file however in my runtime class path I can clearly see the kotlin standard library is in there (version 1.9.0 if that helps). If anyone could help me that would be great.(sorry for an formatting errors, this is my first time posting on stack overflow).

the error I receive is as follows:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
at com.example.entityHighlightMod.onRenderWorldLast(ExampleMod.kt)
at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.ASMEventHandler_0_entityHighlightMod_onRenderWorldLast_RenderWorldLastEvent.invoke(.dynamic)
at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.ASMEventHandler.invoke(ASMEventHandler.java:49)
at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:140)
at net.minecraftforge.client.ForgeHooksClient.dispatchRenderLast(ForgeHooksClient.java:123)
at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.func_175068_a(EntityRenderer.java:1407)
at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.func_78471_a(EntityRenderer.java:1230)
at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.func_181560_a(EntityRenderer.java:1058)
at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71411_J(Minecraft.java:1051)
at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:349)
at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:191)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:182)
... 19 more
```

My build.gradle.kts:

````
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
import java.util.zip.ZipFile

plugins {
    id("idea")
    id("java")
    id("gg.essential.loom") version "0.10.0.+"
    id("dev.architectury.architectury-pack200") version "0.1.3"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "8.1.1"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.0"
}

// Constants:
val baseGroup = "fireballer"
val mcVersion = "1.8.9"
val version = "1"
val mixinGroup = "$baseGroup.mixin"
val modid = "devious"

// Toolchains:
java {
    toolchain.languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of( 8))
}

// Minecraft configuration:
loom {
    log4jConfigs.from(file("log4j2.xml"))
    launchConfigs {
        "client" {
            // If you don't want mixins, remove these lines
            property("mixin.debug", "true")
            property("asmhelper.verbose", "true")
            arg("--tweakClass", "org.spongepowered.asm.launch.MixinTweaker")
            arg("--mixin", "mixins.$modid.json")
        }
    }
    forge {
        pack200Provider.set(dev.architectury.pack200.java.Pack200Adapter())
        // If you don't want mixins, remove this lines
        mixinConfig("mixins.$modid.json")
    }
    // If you don't want mixins, remove these lines
    mixin {
        defaultRefmapName.set("mixins.$modid.refmap.json")
    }
}

sourceSets.main {
    output.resourcesDir = file("$buildDir/classes/java/main")
}

// Dependencies:
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://repo.spongepowered.org/maven/")
    // If you don't want to log in with your real minecraft account, remove this line
    maven("https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/djtheredstoner/DevAuth/_packaging/public/maven/v1")
}

val shadowImpl: Configuration by configurations.creating {
    configurations.implementation.get().extendsFrom(this)
}

dependencies {
    minecraft("com.mojang:minecraft:1.8.9")
    mappings("de.oceanlabs.mcp:mcp_stable:22-1.8.9")
    forge("net.minecraftforge:forge:1.8.9-11.15.1.2318-1.8.9")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0")

    // If you don't want mixins, remove these lines
    shadowImpl("org.spongepowered:mixin:0.7.11-SNAPSHOT") {
        isTransitive = false
    }
    annotationProcessor("org.spongepowered:mixin:0.8.5-SNAPSHOT")

    // If you don't want to log in with your real minecraft account, remove this line
    runtimeOnly("me.djtheredstoner:DevAuth-forge-legacy:1.1.2")
}

// Tasks:
tasks.withType(JavaCompile::class) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

tasks.withType(Jar::class) {
    archiveBaseName.set(modid)
    manifest.attributes.run {
        this["FMLCorePluginContainsFMLMod"] = "true"
        this["ForceLoadAsMod"] = "true"

        // If you don't want mixins, remove these lines
        this["TweakClass"] = "org.spongepowered.asm.launch.MixinTweaker"
        this["MixinConfigs"] = "mixins.$modid.json"
    }
}

tasks.processResources {
    inputs.property("version", project.version)
    inputs.property("mcversion", mcVersion)
    inputs.property("modid", modid)
    inputs.property("mixinGroup", mixinGroup)

    filesMatching(listOf("mcmod.info", "mixins.$modid.json")) {
        expand(inputs.properties)
    }

    rename("(.+_at.cfg)", "META-INF/$1")
}

val remapJar by tasks.named<net.fabricmc.loom.task.RemapJarTask>("remapJar") {
    archiveClassifier.set("")
    from(tasks.shadowJar)
    input.set(tasks.shadowJar.get().archiveFile)
}

tasks.jar {
    archiveClassifier.set("without-deps")
    destinationDirectory.set(layout.buildDirectory.dir("badjars"))
}

tasks.shadowJar {
    destinationDirectory.set(layout.buildDirectory.dir("badjars"))
    archiveClassifier.set("all-dev")
    configurations = listOf(shadowImpl)
    doLast {
        configurations.forEach {
            println("Copying jars into mod: ${it.files}")
        }
    }
}
    // If you want to include other dependencies and shadow them, you can relocate them in here

val compileKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks
compileKotlin.kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
val compileTestKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks
compileTestKotlin.kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}```

my mod.kt file ```
 package com.example

import net.minecraft.command.CommandBase
import net.minecraft.command.ICommandSender
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer
import net.minecraft.entity.projectile.EntityFireball
import net.minecraft.entity.projectile.EntityLargeFireball
import net.minecraft.util.ChatComponentText


class FireballCommand : CommandBase() {
    override fun getCommandName(): String {
        return "fireball"
    }
    override fun getCommandUsage(sender: ICommandSender): String {
        return "/fireball"
    }
    override fun processCommand(sender: ICommandSender, args: Array<String>) {
        if (sender !is EntityPlayer) {
            sender.addChatMessage(ChatComponentText("You must be a player to use this command"))
            return
        }
        val world = sender.entityWorld
        val position = sender.position
        val lookvec = sender.lookVec

        val fireball: EntityFireball = EntityLargeFireball(world, sender, lookvec.xCoord, lookvec.yCoord, lookvec.zCoord)
        fireball.setPosition(position.x.toDouble(), position.y.toDouble(), position.z.toDouble())

        world.spawnEntityInWorld(fireball)

        sender.addChatMessage(ChatComponentText("pow"))
    }
}
````

and my main kotlin class/file:

```
package com.example

import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLServerStartingEvent

@Mod(modid = "fireball", name = "fireball", version = "1.0")
class ExampleMod {
    @Mod.EventHandler
    fun init(event: FMLInitializationEvent) {
    }

    @Mod.EventHandler
    fun serverLoad(event: FMLServerStartingEvent) {
        event.registerServerCommand(FireballCommand())
    }
}
```

[my runtime classpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjs8p.png)

I've added implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0") to the dependencies in hope that it will bundle it but no luck.

Comment: Your build environment has the Kotlin stdlibs, but *Minecraft* doesn't. You should be using [this](https://github.com/thedarkcolour/KotlinForForge/blob/3.x/README.md) or something similar if you are not already.

Comment: Ohhh I see. So I'll have too make a whole new project or is it possible too just change out the gradle files?